# ¿Cómo inicializo un arreglo booleano en true?

Tags: java, array, java-14

¿Cómo inicializo un arreglo booleano en true y después como imprimo por pantalla ese valor true que está en el arreglo?

```
  boolean[] numeros = new  boolean[10];
   for(int i = 0; i < miembros.length; i++){
  System.out.print(" %s ", número[i]);
```

}

Sé que está mal así

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Java usas?

Comment: eclipse 4.17 y JDK 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar la clase `java.util.Arrays` tiene algunos métodos ya hechos para trabajar mejor con arreglos.

```
package es.stackoverflow.com.questions404786;

import java.util.Arrays;

    public class NewClass {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean[] numeros = new boolean[10];
            Arrays.fill(numeros, true);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numeros));;
    
        }
    }
```

Como verás uso el método `fill` para llenar todos los elementos con el mismo valor.
Para representar el arreglo uso el método `toString` también de la clase `Arrays`.

La ventaja de esta solucion como verás es que no usa índices, así que es menos propenso a errores.

Comment: Gracias, no conocía ese método, lo hace mucho más fácil.

Answer (score 1):

Con esta línea:

```
boolean[] numeros = new  boolean[10];
```

Ya tienes un vector con memoria asignada para 10 valores booleanos, lo que procede en este caso es por ejemplo por medio de sus índices asignar valores mas o menos así:

```
numeros[0] = true;
numeros[1] = false;
........
........
```

Ahora para obtener el valor asignado al índice 0 hacemos esto:

```
System.out.println(numeros[0]);
```

O continuando con el ciclo que ya tienes modificalo a esto:

```
System.out.print(numero[i]);
```

Lo anterior te permitirá acceder al valor por cada iteración hecha al vector

**Enlace de interés**

- [Sintaxis de arrays en Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: Gracias, creo que utilizaré la opción del for.

Comment: @Leonardo lo que te convenga mas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un for para ir asignando a cada elemento de tu array el valor true que quieres y justo después mostrarlo por pantalla:

```
boolean[] numeros = new boolean[10];
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
 numeros[i] = true;
 System.out.println(numeros[i]);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder